# Crontab says command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron, ruby

I just setup a cron to restart 'Thin' application server for my Ruby application every hour. I have tried every method but the cron is giving error saying command not found. 
My script looks something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/www/myapp
thin restart -C /etc/thin/myapp
```

(thinrunner is the name of the above bash script)
crontab looks like this

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/thinrunner
```

The error i get in email sent by crontab looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/thinrunner: 3: /usr/local/bin/thinrunner: thin: not found
```

I have also tried running it directly without creating a bash file but it says thin not found even then. I used the following to run directly

```
0 * * * * cd /var/www/myapp && thin restart -C /etc/thin/myapp
```

I have already done chmod +x thinrunner and when i run the script directly, it works as expected. So what could i be doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Check your `PATH`

Comment: @muru thanks. i just gave absolute path for the command as well and it worked :)

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this thread, I solved this by simply giving an absolute path to the `thin` command so that the third line in the bash script was `/usr/local/bin/thin restart -C /etc/thin/myapp`